# How I fix labels in Google Chart?

Tags: php, css, google-visualization

I have this chart and look the dates! There are all together.

[image]

I want like these

[image]

I no have CSS in my php or HTML

I use the code for create the chart

```
function drawCountShopsByCategory(datos) {
    var options5 = {
        is3D : 'true',
        width : 900,
        height : 600
    };
    var chart5 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('CountShopsByCategory'));
    chart5.draw(new google.visualization.DataTable(datos), options5);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
function drawCountShopsByCategory(datos) {
    var options5 = {
        title : 'Cantidad de comercios por categorías',
        is3D : 'true',
        width : 900,
        hAxis: {textPosition: 'out', showTextEvery: 1, slantedText: true, textStyle: { color: '', fontSize: 15 } },
        height :600
    };
    var chart5 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('CountShopsByCategory'));
    chart5.draw(new google.visualization.DataTable(datos), options5);
}
```

Add this line in the optiones!

**hAxis: {textPosition: 'out', showTextEvery: 1, slantedText: true, textStyle: { color: '', fontSize: 15 } }**